# Image corrupted after longer coding session

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

i'm rather new to pharo and I just started another new pharo project (on version 9) and lost my image as the process crashed upon saving.
I cant even load the image anymore.

I have all the changes still in the .changes file, is there any way to file in .changes files into a new image or have Epicea apply those changes?

I can of course manually copy paste all my changes, but that would be a pain with 1500+ lines of unsaved changes.

Happy about any solutions :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In pharo-local/ombu-sessions you'll find the epicea change stored as ombu files. You can use the code changes browser to load them. If you select the directory of them of the crashed process (of course make a backup copy first) you can apply the changes you want